# Regex:find extra space

Tags: c#, regex, space

I have log file and i need to find some parameters.
For example:

```
11:26:42     In [INF] File opened
11:27:48     In   [INF]  some operations
```

And i want to find string numer 2- with extra space.
So, i try to find like this:

```
 string pattern =  @"\[INF\]";
  foreach (String inf in lines)
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(inf, pattern))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(inf);
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputPath, true,Encoding.ASCII))
                    {    
                        file.WriteLine(inf);
                    } 
                }
            }
```

But how to find INF category with extra white space?
I do it via c#, but it doesnt matter.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string pattern =  @"\s\s\[INF\]\s\s";
```

#### [Regex Test](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cs%5Cs%5C%5BINF%5C%5D%5Cs%5Cs&input=11:26:42%20%20%20%20%20In%20%5BINF%5D%20File%20opened%0A11:27:48%20%20%20%20%20In%20%20%20%5BINF%5D%20%20some%20operations%20%0A)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to find double (or more) spaces is

```
@"\s{2,}"
```

This will match the spaces only.